# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: angular

Tags: angular

I am building a page that has tabs - those tabs are dynamics from the DB but to make it simple I defined it manually.

Each tab has a the same radio buttons (there is also a save button and more but to make it simple - I removed it).

When I choose one of the radio buttons I am getting this error

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ui-state-active: false'. Current value: 'ui-state-active: true'.
>   at viewDebugError (core.js:9817)

Also after clicking it again there is no error

Basically the question is how to create radio buttons inside a dynamic tab.

I read this: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/

and this: https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

but since I am new to Angular - I can't understand how to solve my problem.

Here is the full code

```
  <p-tabView>
  <p-tabPanel [header]="category" *ngFor="let category of categoriesList; let i = index" [selected]="i == 0">
    <br>

    <div class="ui-grid-row">
      <h3>Service experience for {{category}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-row">
      <div class="ui-g-6">
        <div class="ui-g-12">
          <p-radioButton name="quickFeedBackGrade" value="1" label="Very poor"
                     [(ngModel)]="categoryGrade" ></p-radioButton>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-12">
          <p-radioButton name="quickFeedBackGrade" value="2" label="Poor"
          [(ngModel)]="categoryGrade" ></p-radioButton>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-12">
          <p-radioButton name="quickFeedBackGrade" value="3" label="Good"
          [(ngModel)]="categoryGrade" ></p-radioButton>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-12">
          <p-radioButton name="quickFeedBackGrade" value="4" label="Very good"
          [(ngModel)]="categoryGrade" ></p-radioButton>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-12">
          <p-radioButton name="quickFeedBackGrade" value="5" label="Ecxelent"
          [(ngModel)]="categoryGrade" ></p-radioButton>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

and the tab.ts holds only the tab building

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: './tabs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabs.component.css']
})
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {

  categoriesList: any = ['tab1' , 'tab2' , 'tab3' , 'tab4' ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the relevant code. The value that it's complaining about is `ui-state-active`. Can you add the component with that property please?

Comment: sorry for some reason it was was displaying the tab part in the html 
i updated the question

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't see `ui-state-active` being used in your template...

Comment: i don't know where it gets it from - i also did not use it 
maybe from the primeNg <p-radioButton >

Comment: I suppose you are in debug (dev) mode. This bug (in fact it's a security checking) occurs when a function detects a change, and you change the changed element, that will fire a change event, leading to changing the changed element, etc. `(onChange) = "displayFeedback($event)"` is probably the source of the problem.

Comment: @RMagen can you comment (or delete temporarily) `this.categoryGrade = this.grades [e.index];` in your `displayFeedback` function ? Does the bug still occur with this?

Comment: any idea how do i fix it ? i need  some how to remember the values the the user chose (this is why i created an array for that ) and display it when he is opening the tab (so i am opening the array for each tab )

Comment: commenting this.categoryGrade = this.grades [e.index]; did not help

Comment: @madjaoue - i tried to comment the  (onChange) = "displayFeedback($event)" 
and i still getting the error

Comment: @RMagen what happens if you remove the `onChange` part ?

Comment: i updated the question - i removed all the function and I am still getting the error basiccaly the Q is how to add radio buttons in a dynamic tabs

Comment: It actually seems to be caused by the `*ngFor` on the `tab-panel`, but I'm not sure why as it seems to match the example given in their docs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to create a `categoryGrade` for each tab.

Change it to an array, like so: `categoryGrade = [];`, then change your `ngModel` so that it becomes `[(ngModel)]="categoryGrade[i]"`.

This way, each tab will have it's own value for `categoryGrade`, and the problem will no longer occur.

**[Here is a working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-jqfxnx?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: thank you I understand my mistake I don't see this error now .
 but still when switching from tab to tab i don't see the previus pick - any idea what causing it ? once it is stored in the categoryGrade[i] it should also display it

Comment: What do you mean? As it stands, the checkboxes on each tab will be independent. Do the tabs need to share the same values? I'm not sure why they're in tabs if each tab is going to be the same

Comment: i mean that if you are in tab 1 and choose "poor"  then go to tab 2 and choose "very good" and then go back to tab1 - you need to see the value "poor" that you chose before

Comment: Sorry, you'll also need to remove the `name` attribute (or find a way of using a unique name for each tab). I've updated the StackBlitz with the name removed